# Elasticsearch-py Index takes 4 arguments, 5 given?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-py

I have the following call to the Elasticsearch-py client:

```
esClient.index(index=data['AppName'], id=data['RequestId'], body=data)
```

I get the following error when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\danielschnoll\dashboard\backend.py", line 52, in main
      parseData(sowSet)
   File "C:\Users\danielschnoll\dashboard\backend.py", line 36, in parseData
      sendToElasticSearch(d)
   File "C:\Users\danielschnoll\dashboard\backend.py", line 39, in sendToElasticSearch
      esClient.index(data['AppName'], id=data['RequestId'], body=data)
   File "C:\elasticsearch-6.2.0-py2.7.egg\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
      return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
TypeError: index() takes at least 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I'm not really sure how I'm getting this error. My 4 arguments are the 'self' call from the esClient, and then the index, id, and body JSON object. Where is this supposed 5th argument and how do I remedy this? Thanks

Comment: Is there a decorator used for `esClient`'s `index` method?

Comment: I don't believe so @Chillie. I've been following this documentation: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.index

Comment: And you're not implementing any custom methods/classes using `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch` as the base class?

Comment: No, nothing like that

Comment: Are you not providing a required argument? What happens if you remove them all or one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is awkward and the documentation lacks an explanation.

You won't make a mistake providing 5 or more arguments - it says **at least** - but you should provide your first argument `index` as the first positional argument and id as the second:

```
esClient.index(data['AppName'], data['RequestId'], body=data)
```

That's [indirectly explained](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) in the link provided just under your linked target in your comment from above, as there's no option to provide an index as an argument, only a direct call to `PUT indexname/...`.

Comment: Does this mean that the call signature in the reathedocs docs is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it was driving me mad last year... XD

Comment: this still didn't resolve the issue. I've updated my post question with the full stack trace. Even with the removed "index=" part of the kwargs I still get the error.

Comment: Have you tried with the id value as an positional argument too?

Comment: that appears to have fixed it! now I have some further debugging to do with the rest of my code, but I don't get that index error anymore. I endorsed your answer, you should update it with the id part so others have that as a reference. thanks!